# Placing one layer above another in css and html

Tags: html, css

As the question speaks,I'm trying to place one layer above the another,for clear explanation see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkopwpco/). I am trying to place the `<div class="booking">` behind `<div class="inputtexts">` but sadly i end by doing the opposite which leads to the affect the brightness of the layer `<div class="inputtexts">`. What I mean is if you could remove the `<div class="booking">` in the fiddle you can see all the text in `<div class="inputtexts">` turns bright.

which means `<div class="booking">` is placed above `<div class="inputtexts">`, but what i wanted is to place `<div class="inputtexts">` above `<div class="booking">` so that text in `<div class="inputtexts">`.

Comment: @Santi I want the dark layer to be at the background and text layer in the front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the 0.4 opacity of the `.booking` also applies to all of its children. If you would just remove the opacity it will work how you want it to.

In case you also want the transparent background, you could use `background` property in CSS with `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)` where first three parmas are RGB values and the last one is the alpha value, 0 being transparent.

Comment: the code worked thankyou so much, I didn't take proper look at  opacity. but still can you please explain why and what is rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)?? please??

Comment: Sure. First three parameters of rgba are Red, Green and Blue values of the color between 0 to 255. For example, 255, 0, 0 will give you red color and 0, 0, 0 will give you black. Similarly, 255, 255, 255 would be white. The last value is the opacity of that color. if it is 0 that means it is completely opaque and if it is 1 that means it is completely transparent. Try out yourself for any value between it, i.e. 0.4